# PySparkTypeError: [CANNOT_INFER_SCHEMA_FOR_TYPE] Can not infer schema for type: `str`. for the spark.createDataFrame(dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables

I have a **pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame**. And i need to write it to a Hive_metastore table, but unable to do so. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df: (df.dtypes)
COL-a      int32
Date       object
COL-b      float64
COL-c      float64
dtype: object
```

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField,StringType, IntegerType, FloatType, DateType

my_schema = StructType(\[
StructField("COL-a", IntegerType(), True),
StructField("Date", DateType(), True),
StructField("COL-b", FloatType(), True),
StructField("COL-c", FloatType(), True),

\])

df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema= my_schema)

# Create a temporary view of the DataFrame

df_spark.createOrReplaceTempView("hello_hi")

# Write the DataFrame to a table in Hive metastore

spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Hive_metastore.Random_loc_1.Final_res AS SELECT \* FROM hello_hi")
```

I get the following error:

`PySparkTypeError:  \[CANNOT_ACCEPT_OBJECT_IN_TYPE\]` StructType`can not accept object`COL-a `in type str`.

Why is it happening and how do I resolve this? Kindly assist please. Any help will be appreciated

Tried everything but somehow unable to resolve this my_schema issue. No chatgpt or Databricks assistant could help me. Even the official spark webpage didn't have a good explanation.

Comment: this issue may have something to do with dashes in the column name, you can try updating those to underscores if possible and test if that works.

Comment: My column does not have hyphens or dashes. Thanks for the reply nontheless :)

Answer (score 0):

`COL-a` is defined as an `IntegerType()` in your schema, but the error indicates it's being treated as a string (str), it seems like there's a data type inconsistency. This is likely be due to the way the pandas DataFrame df is being converted to a PySpark DataFrame.

Can you try this:

```
# Ensure correct data types in pandas DataFrame
df['COL-a'] = df['COL-a'].astype('int32')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  # Assuming 'Date' is in a format pandas can parse
df['COL-b'] = df['COL-b'].astype('float64')
df['COL-c'] = df['COL-c'].astype('float64')

# Let Spark infer the schema
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df_spark.createOrReplaceTempView("hello_hi")

spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Hive_metastore.Random_loc_1.Final_res AS SELECT * FROM hello_hi")
```

Comment: Hello,I get the same error again: :(


PySparkTypeError: [CANNOT_INFER_SCHEMA_FOR_TYPE] Can not infer schema for type: `str`.
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py:898, in <genexpr>(.0)
 infer_array_from_first_element = self._jconf.legacyInferArrayTypeFromFirstElement()
 prefer_timestamp_ntz = is_timestamp_ntz_preferred()
 schema = reduce(
  _merge_type,
( _infer_schema(row,
   names,
 infer_dict_as_struct=infer_dict_as_struct,
 infer_array_from_first_element=infer_array_from_first_element,
 prefer_timestamp_ntz=prefer_timestamp_ntz,
 ) for row in data